# make a label text both justified and right to left direction - iOS

Tags: ios

i'm developing an iOS app. i want to make a label's text justified while it is right to left direction. with textAlignment i can set it justified. then i tried

```
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(self.label)
```

for text direction but it throws exception because of sender object.

```
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a8a22f0'
```

my label is plain text, changing it to attributed is not appropriate for me because i'm using custom font and i can't find it in font family. how can i change it's direction?

Comment: Did you declare the function as following `func makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(_ sender: AnyObject?)` for swift and ` - (void)makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:(id)sender;` for objc ?

Comment: @SaintThread actually i passed label outlet to it as sender argument. but it throws exception

Comment: Yes the compiler tells you that this function is missing.

Comment: @SaintThread should i override it?

Comment: Yes, with swift override `func makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(sender: AnyObject?)`..I am not sure if works but it could be a good attempt. Anyway if you want the left to right direction just for language like Arabic then iOS will provide this behaviour for you.

Comment: @SaintThread if i override it , i should declare function body and this is not something i want. iOS provides this behavior for just iPhones which its language is set to arabic. if device language is english, iOS does nothing, i think